# close all except the selected window

Tags: bash, shell-script, xdotool

I want to close all instance of nemo file browser except the selected window.

I have to following script to do that.

```
#!/bin/bash

not_to_close=$(xdotool selectwindow)
class_name=$(xprop WM_CLASS | cut -d '"' -f2)

for i in $(xdotool search --desktop 0 --class "$class_name"); do
    if [ "$not_to_close" != "$i" ]; then
        xdotool windowclose "$i"
    fi
done
```

However, it has a small problem. I have to click twice (once for `xdotool` once for `xprop`), which I do not want to do.

How can I reduce the click to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace direclty the class by its name, and delete `xprop` line.

```
--class nemo
```

EDIT:
Try out this one, I have tested it with two **xclock** windows, also use `windowkill`  instead of `windowclose`:

```
xclock & 
xclock &
```

Execute the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
not_to_close="$(xdotool selectwindow )"
other_wins="$(xdotool search --class "xclock" | grep -v "$not_to_close")"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
    if [ "$not_to_close" -ne "$line" ]; then
        xdotool windowkill "$line"
    fi
done <<< "$other_wins"
```

Then select one of these two xclock windows, then it will close and the other will remain active.

Comment: It has other issues. Please look at [previous iteration of this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/625132/2). If I select anything other than a nemo instance, it close all nemo windows.

Comment: Check my answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

OP Here, the solution that is working for me is:

```
#!/bin/bash

SELECTED_WINDOW=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
COPY_WINDOW=$(xdotool search --class "nemo" search --classname "file_progress")

WORKSPACE=$(xdotool get_desktop)

for i in $(xdotool search --desktop $WORKSPACE --class "nemo"); do
    if [ "$SELECTED_WINDOW" != "$i" ] && [ "$COPY_WINDOW" != "$i" ] ; then
        xdotool windowclose "$i"
    fi
done
```